# Converting column datatype from VARCHAR to ARRAY in postgres (using Psycopg2)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, postgresql

I have a pandas dataframe df, which I want to store as a schema in a database. By default, it is taking text as the default datatype. I used dtype=sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR argument to save the columns as VARCHAR.

```
df.to_sql('data', con, schema='schema', index= False, dtype=sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR)
```

However, the datatype of one of my column is a multidimensional "array". I tried following code(s), but I am not getting expected output.

```
cursor.execute("
alter table data alter col2 drop default;
alter table data alter col2 type text[][] using array[col2];
alter table data alter col2 set default '{}'");
```

The above code is converting the desired column to text array but the array is empty.

My data looks like this:

```
col1     col2
A1       A1:DEF, Human; X2:XYZ, Mouse;  Y1:RST, Rat
B1       B1:GHI, Human; Y2:ZXY, Mouse
C1       C1:JKL, Human; Z2:USC, Mouse
```

I would like to store col1 as VARCHAR and col2 as multidimensional array of size n, storing each part separated by ';' as one element.

```
For A1:
array[1]: A1:DEF, Human
array[2]: X2:XYZ, Mouse
array[3]: Y1:RST, Rat
```

Any suggestion, how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```sql
alter table data alter col2 drop default;
alter table data alter col2 type text[] using string_to_array(col2, '; ');
alter table data alter col2 set default '{}';
```

Next update the table if you really want to get multidimensional arrays:

```
update data d
set col2 = s.col2
from (
    select col1, array_agg(string_to_array(elem, ', ')) as col2
    from data
    cross join unnest(col2) elem
    group by col1) s
where d.col1 = s.col1;
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f213339252369a0ea6840107cb24d2d)

Comment: Pretty sure OP wants the comma-delimited values to be arrays as well, as the multi dimensional array is mentioned, so the desired result would be `{{"A1:DEF", "Human"}, {"X2:XYZ", "Mouse"}}`

Comment: @404 - I don't think the multidimensional arrays are a good idea but maybe the OP has good reasons for it.

Comment: After using the query:                                                                                           `query = "alter table data alter col2 type text[] using string_to_array(col2, '; ');"                 cursor.execute = (query) `                                                                                             I am getting following error.                                                                             `SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "text"
LINE 1: data ALTER COLUMN type text[] usi...`

Comment: `query = "Alter TABLE data ALTER COLUMN col2 type text[] using string_to_array(col2, ';');"  cursor.execute (query)`
worked fine.